# warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat] C++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
    fprintf( fitxer_sortida, "blob %d ->\t a=%7.0f\t p=%8.2f (%8.2f extern)\t pconvex=%8.2f\t ext=%.0f\t m=%7.2f\t c=%3.2f\t l=%8.2f\n",
                 i, area[i], perimetre[i], externPerimeter[i], perimetreConvex[i], exterior[i], compacitat[i], longitud[i] );
```

and I receive the error:

```
warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: I think that you aren't passing enough arguments.

Comment: You have 9 % arguments in your string and ony 8 data elements in the list

Comment: Up voting because you use the compiler switch!

Comment: I'm guessing the missing parameter is the one corresponding to `m=%7.2f`.  Just a hunch, based off the names...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 9 format specifiers and only 8 following `printf` arguments.

The warning explains itself. It is good that you have not ignored this, because the resulting behavior of this call is *undefined*.

To fix this either add the extra argument or remove one of the format specifiers (`%`).

Comment: Specifically, going by the variable names and the prefixes in the format string, it looks like he's missing the argument that should be printed with `m=%7.2f`.

Comment: @Barmar Such effort! I was going to let the asker work that out. You are so above and beyond!

Answer (score 0):

Your error becomes more evident if you align the format specifiers with their arguments:

```
fprintf(fitxer_sortida,
        "blob %d"  " ->\t a=%7.0f"   "\t p=%8.2f"    " (%8.2f extern)\t "  "pconvex=%8.2f\t "   "ext=%.0f\t "  "m=%7.2f\t "  "c=%3.2f\t "    "l=%8.2f\n",
        i,          area[i],          perimetre[i],  externPerimeter[i],   perimetreConvex[i],  exterior[i],   /* oops */    compacitat[i],   longitud[i]);
```

This does lead to long lines - if you don't like that, consider making more than one call to `fprintf()`.